# Saving Keras model - UserWarning: Layer XX was passed non-serializable keyword arguments

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've just trained and finished my first sequence to sequence model with Keras and now wants to save it so I later can load the model and use it (without having to train it every time). When saving it I do:

```
model.save_weights('models/model_weights.h5')
with open('models/model_architecture.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(model.to_json())
```

But, doing this produces a bunch of user warnings (more or less one for every layer) of the type:

```
path/to/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py:2379: UserWarning: Layer lstm_15 was 
passed non-serializable keyword arguments: {'initial_state': [<tf.Tensor 's0_7:0' 
shape=(?, 64) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'c0_7:0' shape=(?, 64) dtype=float32>]}. 
They will not be included in the serialized model (and thus will be missing at 
deserialization time).
str(node.arguments) + '. They will not be included '
```

Even though just warnings this really puts off the model and accuracy after loading the model.

Everything works perfectly fine right after training (making good predictions, etc.), it's only the saving part that fails. What can I do about this? Anyone else experienced the same thing and solved it somehow? Is there a workaround? May it be any issues with the names I have given the different layers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the model "code", maybe a `.py` file just to create the model exactly as it were.

Then you load weights: `model.load_weights('models/model_weights.h5')`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "save the model code"? Can you give a short example?

Comment: Exactly that. Keep the code you used to create your model so you can create it again. It doesn't sound great, I know, but this serialization problem sounds quite hard to solve.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Hehe. Yes, can of course do that but that means I need to redo the training every time the machine reboots (or something alike), right? Like if having the model up in test environment for others to see, I need to start with training the model and keeping it in memory?

Comment: No, `save_weights`, `load_weights`. All the training is in weights.

Comment: Ah, noow I get it :) Thanks!